# PivotTable cell change

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get the `Dealing Date` cell to change. The cell updates if the code is run on its own, but when put as part of a script it doesn't seem to run:

```
Sub ChngDate()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1)

'pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").ClearAllFilters

' if time is before 12
If Hour(Now) < 12 Then
    pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Date
ElseIf Hour(Now) >= 12 Then
    pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Date + 1
End If

End Sub
```

When running the above I get :

> run-time error 5, invalid procedure or call argument

The PivotTable is the only one on the workbook and located within sheet 1.

Any idea why?

Comment: what line do you get the error on?

Comment: Sorry about that, this line as it is now over 12:

pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Date + 1

Comment: does the value for 10/29/2015 (which is date + 1 as of now) exist in the `Dealing Date` field? If not, the pivot table will not be able to display that date.

Comment: Yes. It seems the +1 is the issue, if i do +2 it works fine. Really weird...

Comment: It's a matter of what dates are available in the `Dealing Date` field at any given time. If the date does not exist, it will not work. You may need to write a statement that checks for the date and if it is not there, make a decision from there.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the issue by putting Date + 1 as a string, slightly strange but did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code by the following one, or other date-pattern, such as `yyyy/MM/dd` :

```
pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Format(Date + 1, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

However, **it won't help you the choose the correct date**. Because these lines modify the current display values.

You can try the following lines :

```
Sub ChngDate()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1)

'pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").ClearAllFilters

' if time is before 12
With pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date")
    If Hour(Now) < 12 Then
        'pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Date
        .PivotItems(Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")).Visible = True
    ElseIf Hour(Now) >= 12 Then
        'pt.PivotFields("Dealing Date").CurrentPage = Date + 1
        .PivotItems(Format(Date + 1, "dd/MM/yyyy")).Visible = True
    End If
End With

End Sub
```